# Writing the mean of values to a new column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new column in my df that holds the mean of another existing column, but I need it to take into account each individual location over time rather then the mean of the all the values in the existing column.

Based on the sample dataset below, what I am looking for is a new column that contains the Mean for each Site, not the mean of all the values independent of Site.

[Sample Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywWvw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use groupby and agg mean of that columns:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('Site',as_index=False).agg({'TIME_HOUR':'mean'})[['Site','TIME_HOUR']],on='Site',how='left')
```

Comment: if I have other columns in the dataframe that I dont want to have the mean calculated in this manner, how do I specific that I want only the 'USED PERCENT' column used to determine mean?  Also, can I write that to a new column using this code: data['USEDPERCENT_MEAN'] = data.merge(data.groupby('SITE',as_index=False).agg({'TIME_HOUR':'mean'})[['SITE','TIME_HOUR']],on='Site',how='left')

Comment: It only calculates mean of time_hour and you don't need to assign it to a new column as a new column will be created and you merge with the original df and you will have a new column there.

Comment: ok thanks, but I don't want mean of time_hour, I wanted mean of used percent. apologies if that was not clear. So how would do that, just substitute Used Percent for time_hour? What would be the name of the newly created column?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('Site')['TIME_HOUR'].mean().reset_index()
```

And assign to a column

Comment: Hi @Wasif Hasan...thanks for the suggestion.  When I ran the following code I get an error...df3['USEDPERCENT_MEAN'] = df3.groupby('SITE')['USEDPERCENT'].mean().reset_index().   ERROR MESSAGE: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1.  Any thoughts?